# NSIS RMDir when dir is open in file manager

Tags: nsis, rmdir

I have an uninstaller where dirs are removed with RMDir and RMDir /r. While debugging i realized that both functions are not working if the dir is opened in a file manager like windows explorer. The dir is not deleted.

Why does this happen. What can i do against this?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/RMDir.md):

> If /REBOOTOK is specified, any file or directory which could not have been removed during the process will be removed on reboot

Comment: ok, but i want to use the uninstaller in an installer. If the programm is already installed i want to uninstall it first and only proceed the installation if the uninstallation was successful.
I don't want to reboot in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure whether there's an applicable way to detect open files, but you could always use [IfFileExists](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/IfFileExists.md) in a loop and display a [MessageBox](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/MessageBox.md) asking the user to close the folder/file

Comment: hm - not very practicable but ok that could be a workaround. If there won't be soo many files and folders...
And i still don't understand why that is a problem for nsis

Comment: It's not a NSIS problem, that's how Windows works. Thinking about it, there are several scenarios that would break the work-around I suggested before. You should think about the likelihood your users end up in this situation. Also, I'd assume your testing scenario left you with an empty folder, what harm does that do if you're reinstalling anyway?

Comment: Well how do i know if it's just an empty folder and not a dll file? My idea was just to install if the uninstallation was successful to make sure the installation is complete and no old files remained.